# Collect py.test tests info with markers

Tags: pytest

I'm using py.test and I want to get the list of tests that I have with marker info included.
When I use the **--collect-only** flag I get the test functions. Is there a way to get the assigned markers for each test also?

---

Based on **Frank T**'s answer I created a workaround code sample:

```
from _pytest.mark import MarkInfo, MarkDecorator
import json


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        '--collect-only-with-markers',
        action='store_true',
        help='Collect the tests with marker information without executing them'
    )


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items):
    if config.getoption('--collect-only-with-markers'):
        for item in items:
            data = {}

            # Collect some general information
            if item.cls:
                data['class'] = item.cls.__name__
            data['name'] = item.name
            if item.originalname:
                data['originalname'] = item.originalname
            data['file'] = item.location[0]

            # Get the marker information
            for key, value in item.keywords.items():
                if isinstance(value, (MarkDecorator, MarkInfo)):
                    if 'marks' not in data:
                        data['marks'] = []

                    data['marks'].append(key)

            print(json.dumps(data))

        # Remove all items (we don't want to execute the tests)
        items.clear()
```

Comment: Markers can now be retrieved with `markers = [mark.name for mark in item.iter_markers()]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think pytest has built-in behavior to list test functions along with the marker information for those tests. A `--markers` command lists all registered markers, but that's not what you want. I briefly looked over the [list of pytest plugins](http://plugincompat.herokuapp.com/) and didn't see anything that looked relevant.

You can write your own pytest plugin to list tests along with marker info. [Here](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#writing-plugins) is documentation on writing a pytest plugin.

I would try using the ["pytest_collection_modifyitems"](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems) hook. It is passed a list of all tests that are collected, and it doesn't need to modify them. ([Here](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#pytest-hook-reference) is a list of all hooks.)

The tests passed in to that hook have a `get_marker()` method if you know the name of the marker you're looking for (see [this code](https://github.com/ftobia/pytest-ordering/blob/develop/pytest_ordering/__init__.py#L51) for example). When I was looking through that code, I could not find an official API for listing all markers. I found this to get the job done: `test.keywords.__dict__['_markers']`  (see [here](https://github.com/ftobia/pytest-ordering/blob/23a9bd9d143b654ef78f8441e06be1b7abe57378/pytest_ordering/__init__.py#L37-L38) and [here](https://github.com/ftobia/pytest-ordering/blob/23a9bd9d143b654ef78f8441e06be1b7abe57378/pytest_ordering/__init__.py#L76-L78)).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I created a workaround based on them.

Answer (score 1):

You can find markers by a `name` attribute in the `request.function.pytestmark` object

```
@pytest.mark.scenarious1
@pytest.mark.scenarious2
@pytest.mark.scenarious3
def test_sample():
    pass

@pytest.fixture(scope='function',autouse=True)
def get_markers():
    print([marker.name for marker in request.function.pytestmark])

>>> ['scenarious3', 'scenarious2', 'scenarious1']
```

Note, that they were listed in the reversed order by default.

Comment: this won't take all markers, only the function ones